# Options not displayed in Ember view Select editable

Tags: javascript, select, ember.js, ember-data, jsbin

I can display all my options value and labels when the view is *not* in the *editable mode*, the problem is that i can not achieve the same when the Ember Select View is in the editable mode.

Here the code in matter:

```
App.ThreadsController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({

   selectContentTariffa: null,

   selectContentTariffa: [
     {label: "180", value: "180"},
     {label: "200", value: "200"},
     {label: "300", value: "300"}
   ],
```

in my view in Editable mode where i can not display the options

```
{{#if editable}}
<td>{{view Ember.Select prompt="Tariffa" content=selectContentTariffa optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label" selectionBinding="selectContentTariffa" valueBinding="content.label"}}</td>
```

in my view when it's not editable and the options are displayed correctly

```
<td>{{view Ember.Select prompt="Tariffa" content=selectContentTariffa optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label"}}</td>
```

Here a jsbin in action to reproduce the issue: http://jsbin.com/begopu/19/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope has changed inside of your each, so the controller is no longer `this` meaning you don't have access to it's properties.  You can alleviate this by using `each item in model` allowing controller/this to still be in scope and the item you are iterating to be scoped as `item`

Example: http://jsbin.com/jumem/1/edit